# How to delete key-value pair from an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable data that contains some key-value pairs like this:

```
var data = {
    "1": 127,
    "2": 236,
    "3": 348
}

router.delete('/values/:id', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;

})
```

How can I delete the key-value pair that has a key equal to the id variable?

Comment: [There's no JSON there!](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `delete data[id]` ?!?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`delete data[req.params.id]` or `delete data[id]` should work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: I didn't expect it to be that easy!